# How to parse response headers in PHP?

Tags: php, api, rest, http-headers

I have made an oauth signed request to a REST API and have the response headers in an array like so:

```
[0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[1] => Cache-Control: private
[2] => Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[3] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
[4] => Content-Location: https://***
[5] => Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
[6] => Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=***; path=/; HttpOnly
[7] => X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
[8] => oauth_token: ***
[9] => oauth_token_secret: ***
[10] => X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
[11] => X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
[12] => Date: Sat, 15 Sep 2012 02:01:15 GMT
```

I am trying to figure out how to parse the headers for easy retrieval of items such as the HTTP status code, Content-Location, oauth_token, and oauth_token_secret?

Comment: It will be simpler / more direct to parse the whole text block with a single regex function call, then call `array_combine()` to form associative elements from the two capture groups (as described in the dupe target).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to iterate the array and check `stripos()` to find the header you're looking for. In most cases, you then `explode()` on `:` (limiting to 2 resultant parts), but the HTTP response code will require you to explode on the spaces.

```
// Get any header except the HTTP response...
function getResponseHeader($header, $response) {
  foreach ($response as $key => $r) {
     // Match the header name up to ':', compare lower case
     if (stripos($r, $header . ':') === 0) {
        list($headername, $headervalue) = explode(":", $r, 2);
        return trim($headervalue);
     }
  }
}
// example:
echo getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
// text/html; charset=utf-8

// Get the HTTP response code
foreach ($response as $key => $r) {
  if (stripos($r, 'HTTP/') === 0) {
    list(,$code, $status) = explode(' ', $r, 3);
    echo "Code: $code, Status: $status";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, you CANNOT do it like this.  This will blindly return headers which dont exist but contain the field name in their value. E.g. getResponseHeader("Session") will return the cookie.

Comment: Response code assumes "HTTP/1.1".  Also contains a bug where only the first word of the status is fetched.  What about "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found".

Comment: @Phil_1984_ This is true. A left-anchored match of the string is necessary to prevent the match in value issue, and slightly more intelligent parsing for the status code with an `explode()` limit. I'll modify these later when I have time (also the function definition doesn't have enough arguments).  You're always free to suggest edits or post a new answer.

Comment: please note that some headers have the same header name like `Set-Cookie` and this function will return only the first header of them.

Comment: Good answer, still accurate with just one problem. Need to consider other HTTP protocol version as now we can have first header looks like "HTTP/2 200". So for all be aware of it in your parsing! It's not limited to `stripos($r, 'HTTP/1.1')` better use `stripos($r, 'HTTP/')`

Comment: @JacekRosłan Excellent addition - I'll modify it above, if you have sufficient rep/privileges, feel free to propose edits to existing answers and include justification. The community will review them.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the only header withou a `:` is the HTTP version and status.
Do an `array_shift` to extract that, iterate through the others creating an array like so:

```
$parsedHeaders = array();
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    if (! preg_match('/^([^:]+):(.*)$/', $header, $output)) continue;
    $parsedArray[$output[1]] = $output[2];
}
```

ps: untested.

— edit —

enjoy ;)

```
/**
 * Parse a set of HTTP headers
 *
 * @param array The php headers to be parsed
 * @param [string] The name of the header to be retrieved
 * @return A header value if a header is passed;
 *         An array with all the headers otherwise
 */
function parseHeaders(array $headers, $header = null)
{
    $output = array();

    if ('HTTP' === substr($headers[0], 0, 4)) {
        list(, $output['status'], $output['status_text']) = explode(' ', $headers[0]);
        unset($headers[0]);
    }

    foreach ($headers as $v) {
        $h = preg_split('/:\s*/', $v);
        $output[strtolower($h[0])] = $h[1];
    }

    if (null !== $header) {
        if (isset($output[strtolower($header)])) {
            return $output[strtolower($header)];
        }

        return;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Your first regex needs delimiters (`/`): `if (! preg_match('/^([^:]):(.*)$/', $header, $output)) continue;`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer if you have pecl_http: http://php.net/manual/it/function.explode.php

Slightly longer answer:

```
$header = "...";
$parsed = array_map(function($x) { return array_map("trim", explode(":", $x, 2)); }, array_filter(array_map("trim", explode("\n", $header))));
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with this solution which uses regex to find all the keys and values in the header combined with some array mutation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43004994/271351 to get the regex matches into an associative array. This isn't 100% appropriate for the problem asked here since it takes in a string, but joining an array of strings to get a single string would work as a precursor to this. My case had to deal with raw headers, thus this solution.

```php
preg_match_all('/^([^:\n]*): ?(.*)$/m', $header, $headers, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$headers = array_merge(...array_map(function ($set) {
    return array($set[1] => trim($set[2]));
}, $headers));
```

This yields an associative array of the headers. If the first line of the headers is included as input (e.g. `GET / HTTP/1.1`), this will ignore it for the output.

Answer (score 1):

best way without http_parse_headers();

```
function strHeaders2Hash($r) {
    $o = array();
    $r = substr($r, stripos($r, "\r\n"));
    $r = explode("\r\n", $r);
    foreach ($r as $h) {
        list($v, $val) = explode(": ", $h);
        if ($v == null) continue;
        $o[$v] = $val;
    }
    return $o;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  Why is this the "best way"?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `get_headers` function, if so, use the second parameter of the this function which replaces the numerical values for the output array keys and replaces them with string keys, check out the [**manual**](https://www.php.net/get_headers) for get_headers function.

a small example would be:

```
<?php
    $output = get_headers('http://google.com', 1);
    print_r($output);
```

will produce something like the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
    [Location] => http://www.google.com/
    [Content-Type] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
            [1] => text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
        )

    [Date] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tue, 24 Sep 2013 11:57:10 GMT
            [1] => Tue, 24 Sep 2013 11:57:11 GMT
        )

    [Expires] => Array
        (
            [0] => Thu, 24 Oct 2013 11:57:10 GMT
            [1] => -1
        )

    [Cache-Control] => Array
        (
            [0] => public, max-age=2592000
            [1] => private, max-age=0
        )

    [Server] => Array
        (
            [0] => gws
            [1] => gws
        )

    [Content-Length] => 219
    [X-XSS-Protection] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1; mode=block
            [1] => 1; mode=block
        )

    [X-Frame-Options] => Array
        (
            [0] => SAMEORIGIN
            [1] => SAMEORIGIN
        )

    [Alternate-Protocol] => Array
        (
            [0] => 80:quic
            [1] => 80:quic
        )

    [1] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    [Set-Cookie] => Array
        (
            [0] => PREF=ID=58c8f706594fae17:FF=0:TM=1380023831:LM=1380023831:S=_ehOnNWODZqIarXn; expires=Thu, 24-Sep-2015 11:57:11 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
            [1] => NID=67=L85IlJW5yG4l9Suyf1LwKMUTcVHyGv4u9tuuMlBH4pfT1syOJvspcgRJ9uTde1xLTDhI2QcOG_fuJY3sfhw49mayT5WdMHnGeMyhh3SgFTRYVF0RAtBXXmjyDFzMqPKu; expires=Wed, 26-Mar-2014 11:57:11 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
        )

    [P3P] => CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be extra-safe, use Symfony HTTP Foundation:

`composer require symfony/http-foundation`

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// retrieves an HTTP request header, with normalized, lowercase keys
$request->headers->get('host');
$request->headers->get('content-type');
```

If you'd rather not have that dependency, here's an example that I've put together to find out if the `Cache-Control` header has the `no-cache` value, for instance:

```
/**
*  [
*    0 => 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-validate',
*    1 => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0',
*  ]
*/
$headers = headers_list();

foreach ( $headers as $header_string ) {
     /*
     * Regex Samples:
     * "Foo: Bar"
     * "Foo-Bar: Baz-Bar:1"
     *
     * Matches:
     * "Foo"
     * "Foo-Bar"
     */
    preg_match( '#^.+?(?=:)#', $header_string, $key );

    if ( empty( $key ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    $key   = strtolower( reset( $key ) );
    $value = strtolower( ltrim( strtolower( $header_string ), $key . ':' ) );

    if ( $key == 'cache-control' ) {
        if ( strpos( $value, 'no-cache' ) !== false || strpos( $value, 'no-store' ) !== false ) {
            $nocache = true;
        }
    }
}
```