# Access first level keys with array_map() without calling `array_keys()`

Tags: php, arrays, functional-programming, array-map

Is there a way of doing something like this:

```
$test_array = array(
    "first_key" => "first_value", 
    "second_key" => "second_value"
);

var_dump(
    array_map(
        function($a, $b) {
            return "$a loves $b";
        }, 
        array_keys($test_array), 
        array_values($test_array)
    )
);
```

But instead of calling `array_keys` and `array_values`, directly passing the `$test_array` variable?

The desired output is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(27) "first_key loves first_value"
  [1]=>
  string(29) "second_key loves second_value"
}
```

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Not with array_map, as it doesn't handle keys.

[array_walk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) does:

```
$test_array = array("first_key" => "first_value",
                    "second_key" => "second_value");
array_walk($test_array, function(&$a, $b) { $a = "$b loves $a"; });
var_dump($test_array);

// array(2) {
//   ["first_key"]=>
//   string(27) "first_key loves first_value"
//   ["second_key"]=>
//   string(29) "second_key loves second_value"
// }
```

It does change the array given as parameter however, so it's not exactly functional programming (as you have the question tagged like that). Also, as pointed out in the comment, this will only change the values of the array, so the keys won't be what you specified in the question.

You could write a function that fixes the points above yourself if you wanted to, like this:

```
function mymapper($arrayparam, $valuecallback) {
  $resultarr = array();
  foreach ($arrayparam as $key => $value) {
    $resultarr[] = $valuecallback($key, $value);
  }
  return $resultarr;
}

$test_array = array("first_key" => "first_value",
                    "second_key" => "second_value");
$new_array = mymapper($test_array, function($a, $b) { return "$a loves $b"; });
var_dump($new_array);

// array(2) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(27) "first_key loves first_value"
//   [1]=>
//   string(29) "second_key loves second_value"
// }
```

Comment: Except that in this case, you want `$a = "$b loves $a"`, to match the OP's desired output.

Comment: correct, changed :) it is nice how different they've made array_map from array_walk.

Comment: Nice, thanks. In order to avoid messing the original array, here's what I eventually did (look my answer below)

Comment: This is not "functional-programming" though since `array_walk()` does not return the resulting array, but a bool instead.

Comment: @mae yes, like I wrote in the answer as well - instead of returning the value it changes the parameter

Comment: array_map will handle keys and anything else you provide it. It's the most idiomatic solution.

Comment: it does not return desired output , instead it gives 
`array:2 [
  "first_key" => "first_key loves first_value"
  "second_key" => "second_key loves second_value"
]`

Comment: @AndrewVakhniuk correct, it only changes the values, not the keys. however I think the main point of this question were the values. You can alter the keys as well in the function given as parameter if needed.

Comment: @eis i tried with that function, i can not change the key, instead i am unsetting the  element from the array and adding new one with needed key

Comment: ah. I also checked and apparently you really can't change the key in the way code is written in this answer. Good point.

Answer (score 224):

This is probably the shortest and easiest to reason about:

```
$states = array('az' => 'Arizona', 'al' => 'Alabama');

array_map(function ($short, $long) {
    return array(
        'short' => $short,
        'long'  => $long
    );
}, array_keys($states), $states);

// produces:
array(
     array('short' => 'az', 'long' => 'Arizona'), 
     array('short' => 'al', 'long' => 'Alabama')
)
```

Comment: I just realized that the question specifically said not to use `array_keys()`. That seems like a silly requirement, though.

Comment: The question provided a solution using array_keys(), it would be silly to provide an answer that has no advantage (eg, calling less functions) over the current solution.

Comment: The answer to the original question is NO, and this is the most appropriate solution.

Comment: This answer has ignored the sample data and desired output of the asked question.

Comment: How could this get to many upvotes? This returns an array of arrays, which is *NOT* the expected output (an array of 2 items). It's very different structures so this answer is wrong.

Comment: @V.Högman That's so funny. I never noticed that before. My reading comprehension is not as good as I thought, haha. I must have just read the title. Maybe the people upvoting also came here because of the title (which used to be different).

Answer (score 96):

Here's my very simple, PHP 5.5-compatible solution:

```
function array_map_assoc(callable $f, array $a) {
    return array_column(array_map($f, array_keys($a), $a), 1, 0);
}
```

The callable you supply should itself return an array with two values, i.e. `return [key, value]`. The inner call to [`array_map`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) therefore produces an array of arrays. This then gets converted back to a single-dimension array by [`array_column`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

#### Usage

```
$ordinals = [
    'first' => '1st',
    'second' => '2nd',
    'third' => '3rd',
];

$func = function ($k, $v) {
    return ['new ' . $k, 'new ' . $v];
};

var_dump(array_map_assoc($func, $ordinals));
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  ["new first"]=>
  string(7) "new 1st"
  ["new second"]=>
  string(7) "new 2nd"
  ["new third"]=>
  string(7) "new 3rd"
}
```

#### Partial application

In case you need to use the function many times with different arrays but the same mapping function, you can do something called [partial function application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23438430/760706) (related to ‘[currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)’), which allows you to only pass in the data array upon invocation:

```
function array_map_assoc_partial(callable $f) {
    return function (array $a) use ($f) {
        return array_column(array_map($f, array_keys($a), $a), 1, 0);
    };
}

...
$my_mapping = array_map_assoc_partial($func);
var_dump($my_mapping($ordinals));
```

Which produces the same output, given `$func` and `$ordinals` are as earlier.

NOTE: if your mapped function returns the **same key** for two different inputs, the value associated with **the later key will win.** Reverse the input array and output result of `array_map_assoc` to allow earlier keys to win. (The returned keys in my example cannot collide as they incorporate the key of the source array, which in turn must be unique.)

---

## Alternative

Following is a variant of the above, which might prove more logical to some, but requires PHP 5.6:

```
function array_map_assoc(callable $f, array $a) {
    return array_merge(...array_map($f, array_keys($a), $a));
}
```

In this variant, your supplied function (over which the data array is mapped) should instead return an associative array with one row, i.e. `return [key => value]`.
The result of mapping the callable is then simply unpacked and passed to `array_merge`. As earlier, returning a duplicate key will result in later values winning.

> n.b. Alex83690 has noted in a comment that using `array_replace` here in the stead of `array_merge` would preserve integer keys. `array_replace` does not modify the input array, so is safe for functional code.

If you are on PHP 5.3 to 5.5, the following is equivalent. It uses `array_reduce` and the binary `+` array operator to convert the resulting two-dimensional array down to a one-dimensional array whilst preserving keys:

```
function array_map_assoc(callable $f, array $a) {
    return array_reduce(array_map($f, array_keys($a), $a), function (array $acc, array $a) {
        return $acc + $a;
    }, []);
}
```

#### Usage

Both of these variants would be used thus:

```
$ordinals = [
    'first' => '1st',
    'second' => '2nd',
    'third' => '3rd',
];

$func = function ($k, $v) {
    return ['new ' . $k => 'new ' . $v];
};

var_dump(array_map_assoc($func, $ordinals));
```

**Note the `=>` instead of `,` in `$func`.**

The output is the same as before, and each can be partially applied in the same way as before.

---

## Summary

The goal of the original question is to make the invocation of the call as simple as possible, at the expense of having a more complicated function that gets invoked; especially, to have the ability to pass the data array in as a single argument, without splitting the keys and values. Using the function supplied at the start of this answer:

```
$test_array = ["first_key" => "first_value",
               "second_key" => "second_value"];

$array_map_assoc = function (callable $f, array $a) {
    return array_column(array_map($f, array_keys($a), $a), 1, 0);
};

$f = function ($key, $value) {
    return [$key, $key . ' loves ' . $value];
};

var_dump(array_values($array_map_assoc($f, $test_array)));
```

Or, for this question only, we can make a simplification to `array_map_assoc()` function that drops output keys, since the question does not ask for them:

```
$test_array = ["first_key" => "first_value",
               "second_key" => "second_value"];

$array_map_assoc = function (callable $f, array $a) {
    return array_map($f, array_keys($a), $a);
};

$f = function ($key, $value) {
    return $key . ' loves ' . $value;
};

var_dump($array_map_assoc($f, $test_array));
```

So the answer is **NO**, you can't avoid calling `array_keys`, but you can abstract out the place where `array_keys` gets called into a higher-order function, which might be good enough.

Comment: [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is PHP 5.5+ only, so this answer is not compatible with PHP 5.3

Comment: I'll be THAT guy.  PHP 5.3 should no longer be a requirement for the date of *this* answer. IMHO.

Comment: @Erutan409 Sure, I just wanted to provide as versatile an answer as I could. I do like running new code on old systems though. I have Netscape 1.0 running on on an old Mac with System 7.1 which I occasionally go browsing the web with, just to give sys admins a fright when they look in their server logs :-)

Comment: Your first alternative solution in invalid. you must replace `array_merge` by `array_replace` to preserve keys that would be integers.

Comment: @Alex83690 Thanks! Though I'd say "invalid' is slightly misleading — it is fine if you do not have any integer keys (as was true in my own case).

Comment: If some interested in array-mapping function that preserves keys and at the same time it's callback has access to both key and value, and can return just a value (as normal mapping function do) instead of "specially formatted" value (an associative array with one row), then here is slightly modified php 5.6 solution: `function array_map_assoc(callable $f, array $a) { return array_merge(...array_map(function ($k, $v) use ($f) { return [ $k => $f($k, $v) ]; }, array_keys($a), $a)); }`. For this to work, the `$f` must be wrapped with another function, that maps new value to `[key=>new_value]`.

Answer (score 64):

```
$array = [
    'category1' => 'first category',
    'category2' => 'second category',
];

$new = array_map(function ($key, $value) {
    return "{$key} => {$value}";
}, array_keys($array), $array);
```

Answer (score 21):

With PHP5.3 or later:

```
$test_array = array("first_key" => "first_value", 
                    "second_key" => "second_value");

var_dump(
    array_map(
        function($key) use ($test_array) { return "$key loves ${test_array[$key]}"; },
        array_keys($test_array)
    )
);
```

Comment: I think the requirement was "instead of calling array_keys and array_values, directly passing the $test_array variable", can this be used without array_keys?

Answer (score 8):

I'll add yet another solution to the problem using version 5.6 or later. Don't know if it's more efficient than the already great solutions (probably not), but to me it's just simpler to read:

```
$myArray = [
    "key0" => 0,
    "key1" => 1,
    "key2" => 2
];

array_combine(
    array_keys($myArray),
    array_map(
        function ($intVal) {
            return strval($intVal);
        },
        $myArray
    )
);
```

Using `strval()` as an example function in the `array_map`, this will generate:

```
array(3) {
  ["key0"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["key1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["key2"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

Hopefully I'm not the only one who finds this pretty simple to grasp.
`array_combine` creates a `key => value` array from an array of keys and an array of values, the rest is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for array_combine() to combine with array_map() to generate new key => value pairs: `array_combine(array_values($arr), array_map(..., $arr))`

Comment: [Simpler version of this answer ](https://3v4l.org/36r4j)

Comment: This answer has ignored the sample data and desired output of the asked question.

Answer (score 6):

**Look here! There is a trivial solution!**

```
function array_map2(callable $f, array $a)
{
    return array_map($f, array_keys($a), $a);
}
```

As stated in the question, `array_map` *already has exactly the functionality required*. The other answers here seriously overcomplicate things: `array_walk` is not functional.

**Usage**

Exactly as you would expect from your example:

```
$test_array = array("first_key" => "first_value", 
                    "second_key" => "second_value");

var_dump(array_map2(function($a, $b) { return "$a loves $b"; }, $test_array));
```

Comment: the other answers overcomplicate things because the question specified `qrrqy_keys()` shouldn't be used for #reasons

Answer (score 3):

By "manual loop" I meant write a custom function that uses `foreach`. This returns a new array like `array_map` does because the function's scope causes `$array` to be a copy—not a reference:

```
function map($array, callable $fn) {
  foreach ($array as $k => &$v) $v = call_user_func($fn, $k, $v);
  return $array;
}
```

Your technique using `array_map` with `array_keys` though actually seems simpler and is more powerful because you can use `null` as a callback to return the key-value pairs:

```
function map($array, callable $fn = null) {
  return array_map($fn, array_keys($array), $array);
}
```

Comment: looping array with reference, can cause [spooky things to happen](http://phpmaster.com/spooky-scary-php/)

Comment: It's not spooky, it just means you forgot to `unset( $value )` because it still exists in the defined scope.

Comment: @azis, was kidding about the spookiness, referring to the article. It will create unexpected effects if you forget to unset.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I thought it was pretty clear that I didn't want to use a traditional loop.

Comment: @janenz00 See edited answer for clarification. I meant looping in a clean variable scope.

Comment: Your parameters should be passed in the other way around. It is more versatile, and standard practice in FP, to have the 'data' last and the 'operation' first.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've implemented this in my project.

```
function array_map_associative(callable $callback, $array) {
    /* map original array keys, and call $callable with $key and value of $key from original array. */
    return array_map(function($key) use ($callback, $array){
        return $callback($key, $array[$key]);
    }, array_keys($array));
}
```

Comment: Very clean, and doesn't alter the original array!

Answer (score 3):

A [closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) would work if you only need it once. I'd use a [generator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php).

```
$test_array = [
    "first_key" => "first_value", 
    "second_key" => "second_value",
];

$x_result = (function(array $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        yield "$key loves $value";
    }
})($test_array);

var_dump(iterator_to_array($x_result));

// array(2) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(27) "first_key loves first_value"
//   [1]=>
//   string(29) "second_key loves second_value"
// }
```

For something reusable:

```
function xmap(callable $cb, array $arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        yield $cb($key, $value);
    }
}

var_dump(iterator_to_array(
    xmap(function($a, $b) { return "$a loves $b"; }, $test_array)
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [eis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13036310/276451), here's what I eventually did in order to avoid messing the original array:

```
$test_array = array("first_key" => "first_value",
                    "second_key" => "second_value");

$result_array = array();
array_walk($test_array, 
           function($a, $b) use (&$result_array) 
           { $result_array[] = "$b loves $a"; }, 
           $result_array);
var_dump($result_array);
```

Comment: Why is this easier than just passing the array values and keys directly to array_map? It's slower and more complicated, I'm not seeing the advantage.

Comment: @Ariel can you back up the claim that it would be slower, even with big numbers? It needs to iterate the array only once, so I think it should be magnitudes faster in big O notation. I agree about complexity though.

Comment: @eis It's slower because it's creating the result array one at a time in PHP, instead of en masse in C. It does avoid the array_keys call though (although that's fast since it's in C). Benchmark it - see which is faster, I'm not really certain, but usually more code = slower code. In complexity it's definitely worse though, and that's more important than speed most of the time.

Comment: You do not need to send the third arg to `array_walk` as you are not referencing it in the closure.

Answer (score 1):

I made this function, based on [eis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13036310/276451):

```
function array_map_($callback, $arr) {
    if (!is_callable($callback))
        return $arr;

    $result = array_walk($arr, function(&$value, $key) use ($callback) {
        $value = call_user_func($callback, $key, $value);
    });

    if (!$result)
        return false;

    return $arr;
}
```

Example:

```
$test_array = array("first_key" => "first_value", 
                "second_key" => "second_value");

var_dump(array_map_(function($key, $value){
    return $key . " loves " . $value;
}, $arr));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'first_key' => 'first_key loves first_value,
  'second_key' => 'second_key loves second_value',
)
```

Off course, you can use `array_values` to return exactly what OP wants.

```
array_values(array_map_(function($key, $value){
    return $key . " loves " . $value;
}, $test_array))
```

Comment: @KevinBeal I use this function a lot in my work. Could you point where is the errors?

Comment: Firstly, the code as it stands is missing a check that `$arr` is of type array, however if you type-hint your arguments as `callable` and `array` you can instead drop the check to `is_callable`. Next, you make an assignment to $value that is then unused. You should just ignore the return value. Thirdly, it would be better to throw an exception in the callback than to return false. You would then either always return a valid value or always throw.

Answer (score 1):

[YaLinqo](https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo) library* is well suited for this sort of task. It's a port of LINQ from .NET which fully supports values and keys in all callbacks and resembles SQL. For example:

```
$mapped_array = from($test_array)
    ->select(function ($v, $k) { return "$k loves $v"; })
    ->toArray();
```

or just:

```
$mapped_iterator = from($test_array)->select('"$k loves $v"');
```

Here, `'"$k loves $v"'` is a shortcut for full closure syntax which this library supports. `toArray()` in the end is optional. The method chain returns an iterator, so if the result just needs to be iterated over using `foreach`, `toArray` call can be removed.

<sub>* developed by me</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I always like the javascript variant of array map. The most simple version of it would be:

```
/**
 * @param  array    $array
 * @param  callable $callback
 * @return array
 */
function arrayMap(array $array, callable $callback)
{
    $newArray = [];

    foreach( $array as $key => $value )
    {
        $newArray[] = call_user_func($callback, $value, $key, $array);
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

So now you can just pass it a callback function how to construct the values.

```
$testArray = [
    "first_key" => "first_value", 
    "second_key" => "second_value"
];

var_dump(
    arrayMap($testArray, function($value, $key) {
        return $key . ' loves ' . $value;
    });
);
```

Comment: It is more useful to have the data as the last argument to any function you write, as you can then create a new function that bakes-in some specific callback (behaviour) — i.e. you get function composition: `h(g(f($data)))` applies `f`, then `g`, then `h` to your data. It is generally considered more versatile in functional programming to have a function that performs the same operation on divers data, than to have a function that applies divers functions to a fixed data set.

Comment: In your example you have only 1 argument to the function. I find it easier to put the data as first argument, like array_filter, array_reduce and the array functions in javascript.

Comment: That's my point! By passing the data last, it allows you to curry the function (create a new function that combines the looping with the specific operation) and apply *that* to the data by calling the new function with a single parameter. This principal is explained better than I can here, in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5863222

Comment: Is using a compose function in a language like PHP not a better solution to this problem?

Comment: It's an alternative but requires substantially more investment in FP, for example this: https://github.com/nickshanks/fp-php-talk/blob/master/lib.php#L24 or this: https://github.com/nickshanks/php-fp/blob/master/src/fp.php#L62

Comment: `foreach` isn't convoluted enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```php
<?php

/**
 * array_map_kv()
 *   An array mapping function to map with both keys and values.
 *
 * @param $callback callable
 *   A callback function($key, $value) for mapping values.
 * @param $array array
 *   An array for mapping.
 */
function array_map_kv(callable $callback, array $array) {
  return array_map(
    function ($key) use ($callback, $array) {
      return $callback($key, $array[$key]); // $callback($key, $value)
    },
    array_keys($array)
  );
}

// use it
var_dump(array_map_kv(function ($key, $value) {
  return "{$key} loves {$value}";
}, array(
  "first_key" => "first_value",
  "second_key" => "second_value",
)));

?>
```

Results:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(27) "first_key loves first_value"
  [1]=>
  string(29) "second_key loves second_value"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://minwork.gitbook.io/array/manipulating-array/mapping#map) method from this [array library](https://packagist.org/packages/minwork/array) to achieve exactly what you want as easily as:

```php
Arr::map($test_array, function($a, $b) { return "$a loves $b"; });
```

also it preserves keys and returns new array, not to mention few different modes to fit your needs.

Comment: Why using a library also `array_map` function with key do the job ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this with(out) preserving keys:

```
$test_array = [
    "first_key"     => "first_value",
    "second_key"    => "second_value"
];

$f = function($ar) {
    return array_map(
        function($key, $val) {
            return "{$key} - {$val}";
        },
        array_keys($ar),
        $ar
    );
};

#-- WITHOUT preserving keys
$res = $f($test_array);

#-- WITH preserving keys
$res = array_combine(
    array_keys($test_array),
    $f($test_array)
);
```

Answer (score -2):

I see it's missing the obvious answer:

```
function array_map_assoc(){
    if(func_num_args() < 2) throw new \BadFuncionCallException('Missing parameters');

    $args = func_get_args();
    $callback = $args[0];

    if(!is_callable($callback)) throw new \InvalidArgumentException('First parameter musst be callable');

    $arrays = array_slice($args, 1);

    array_walk($arrays, function(&$a){
        $a = (array)$a;
        reset($a);
    });

    $results = array();
    $max_length = max(array_map('count', $arrays));

    $arrays = array_map(function($pole) use ($max_length){
        return array_pad($pole, $max_length, null);
    }, $arrays);

    for($i=0; $i < $max_length; $i++){
        $elements = array();
        foreach($arrays as &$v){
            $elements[] = each($v);
        }
        unset($v);

        $out = call_user_func_array($callback, $elements);

        if($out === null) continue;

        $val = isset($out[1]) ? $out[1] : null;

        if(isset($out[0])){
            $results[$out[0]] = $val;
        }else{
            $results[] = $val;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Works exactly like array_map. Almost.

Actually, it's not pure `map` as you know it from other languages. Php is very weird, so it requires some very weird user functions, for we don't want to unbreak our precisely broken `worse is better` approach.

Really, it's not actually `map` at all. Yet, it's still very useful.

- First obvious difference from array_map, is that the callback takes outputs of `each()` from every input array instead of value alone. You can still iterate through more arrays at once.
- Second difference is the way the key is handled after it's returned from callback; the return value from callback function should be `array('new_key', 'new_value')`. Keys can and will be changed, same keys can even cause previous value being overwritten, if same key was returned. This is not common `map` behavior, yet it allows you to rewrite keys.
- Third weird thing is, if you omit `key` in return value (either by `array(1 => 'value')` or `array(null, 'value')`), new key is going to be assigned, as if `$array[] = $value` was used. That isn't `map`'s common behavior either, yet it comes handy sometimes, I guess.
- Fourth weird thing is, if callback function doesn't return a value, or returns `null`, the whole set of current keys and values is omitted from the output, it's simply skipped. This feature is totally un`map`py, yet it would make this function excellent stunt double for `array_filter_assoc`, if there was such function.
- If you omit second element (`1 => ...`) (the **value** part) in callback's return, `null` is used instead of real value.
- Any other elements except those with keys `0` and `1` in callback's return are ignored.
- And finally, if lambda returns any value except of `null` or array, it's treated as if both key and value were omitted, so:

  1. new key for element is assigned
  2. `null` is used as it's value

> WARNING:
> Bear in mind, that this last feature is just a residue of previous features and it is probably completely useless. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged, as this feature is going to be randomly **deprecated** and changed unexpectedly in future releases.

NOTE:
Unlike in `array_map`, all non-array parameters passed to `array_map_assoc`, with the exception of first callback parameter, are silently casted to arrays.

EXAMPLES:
`// TODO: examples, anyone?`