# convert array to dictionary in php

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

I have array (returns from database), looks like this:

```
response = {
    0 = {
        id = "12312132",
        title = "title1",
        ....
        createDT = "2015-03-03 22:53:17"
        }
    1 = {
        id = "456456456",
        title = "title2",
        ....
        createDT = "2015-03-03 22:53:17"
        }
    2 = {
        id = "789789789",
        title = "title3",
        ....
        createDT = "2015-03-03 22:53:17"
        }
    }
```

I need to convert this in dictionary use php like this:

```
response = {
    "12312132" = {
        title = "title1",
        ....
        createDT = "2015-03-03 22:53:17"
        }
    "456456456" = {
        title = "title2",
        ....
        createDT = "2015-03-03 22:53:17"
        }
    "789789789" = {
        title = "title3",
        ....
        createDT = "2015-03-03 22:53:17"
        }
    }
```

i.e. `key` is `id`. Perhaps there is some function in php, for do it easy?

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing of `dictionary` term in PHP. What you actually mean is an `associative array`, also commonly known as a `hash`. The same thing though, but this can make it easier to google up in future.

You can do it in several ways, I will give you classic `foreach()` one. <del>I think `array_map()` approach would be possible too.</del>

```
$response = ...;        // your database response
$converted = array();   // declaring some clean array, just to be sure

foreach ($response as $row) {
    $converted[$row['id']] = $row;        // entire row (for example $response[1]) is copied 
    unset($converted[$row['id']]['id']);  // deleting element with key 'id' as we don't need it anymore inside
}
print_r($converted);
```

Comment: The problem with `array_map` is that it can't work on keys. A foreach loop is often faster anyway.

Comment: @Niols Thanks, I wasn't sure. I'm not big fan of `array_map` and `array_walk` and don't know everything about them.

Comment: It might be possible with `array_walk` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036160/phps-array-map-including-keys?answertab=votes#tab-top). But yeah, that wont be an efficient code.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can write a little program in PHP:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($response as $row)
{
  $id = $row['id'];
  unset($row['id']);
  $result[$id] = $row;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

And even make that into your own function:

```
function dictonary($response) 
{
  $result = array();
  foreach ($response as $row)
  { 
    $id = $row['id'];
    unset($row['id']);
    $result[$id] = $row;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: And before that loop `$result = array();`

Comment: @n-dru: Yes it is good practice to initialize. I will add it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using `array_combine` and `array_column`, like this :

```php
$result = array_combine(array_column($response, 'id'), $response);
```

Basically, this :

- extracts an array of the values of `id`s
- use this list as key for a new array, using `$response` as values.

Comment: Excellent answer, I love one-liners!

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the results to populate the array again in new format

```
    $count = count($response) // count the items of your initial array
    $i=0;
    while($i<$count) { //start a loop to populate new array
    $key = $response[i]['id'];
    $new_response[$key] = array('title' =>  $response[i]['title'], ... ,'createDT' => $response[i]['createDT']);
    $i++;
    } // end loop

print_r($new_response);
```

Comment: Please do not just post code without explaining what we're looking at.