# Hack iterate (map) over Map

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

I have a `Map` such as:

```
$m = Map {
  'sort' => 'created',
  'order' => 'desc',
}
```

I want to turn that into a string:

```
'sort:created order:desc'
```

I can do this with arrays as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30539355/90998):

```
implode(' ', array_map(($k, $v) ==> $k.':'.$v, array_keys($m), $m))
```

I've read the documentation of [`Map::items`](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/class/Map/items/) and tried:

```
$m->items()->map(($key, $value) ==> print($key))
```

But this prints nothing.

I'm looking for a oneliner like with the arrays, no loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map()`'s parameter is a function that only takes one argument; if you run the typechecker, it will tell you this:

```
test.php:9:20,20: Invalid argument (Typing[4039])
  /tmp/hh_server/hhi_1ebd4af3/hhi/interfaces.hhi:363:27,44: Number of  arguments doesn't match
  test.php:9:20,20: Because of this definition
```

What you want is `mapWithKey()` https://3v4l.org/GF69D:

```
$m->mapWithKey(($key, $value) ==> print($key));
```

You can also use exactly the same code you were using for arrays: https://3v4l.org/mSREI

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
implode(' ', $m->mapWithKey(($k, $v) ==> $k.':'.$v))
```