# Merging JSON objects with same key together

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I need to merge JSON objects with same key into one so that it gets an object or array(doesn't matter if result is an object or array) which holds the key and an array for the values

example JSON object:

```
[{
    "meine_frage": "hier kommt die antwort",
    "ne_andere_frage": "ne andere antwort",
    "was_willst_du": "alles",
    "mehr_zur_auswahl": ["einiges", "vieles und", "g\u00e4r nix"]

}, {
    "meine_frage": "tom & jerry",
    "ne_andere_frage": "mickey maus",
    "was_willst_du": "oder",
    "mehr_zur_auswahl": ["manches", "einiges", "vieles und", "g\u00e4r nix"]

}, {
    "meine_frage": "dick und doof",
    "ne_andere_frage": "minnie muas",
    "was_willst_du": "nichts",
    "mehr_zur_auswahl": ["g\u00e4r nix"]

}]
```

result should look like:

```
[{
    "meine_frage": ["hier kommt die antwort", "tom & jerry", "dick und doof"],
    "ne_andere_frage": ["ne andere antwort", "mickey maus", "minnie muas"],
    "was_willst_du": ["alles", "oder"],
    "mehr_zur_auswahl": ["einiges", "vieles und", "g\u00e4r nix", "manches", "einiges", "vieles und", "g\u00e4r nix"]
}]
```

some values are already arrays whereas others not, the keys are genterated dynamically so assume the the key name is unkown

i tried iterating over the key/values with $.each and for loops but without success, also searched the web but couldnt find similar,
appreciate any help

Comment: where is your js code?

Comment: thank you all for your quick answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and `concat()` methods for this.

```js
const data = [{"meine_frage":"hier kommt die antwort","ne_andere_frage":"ne andere antwort","was_willst_du":"alles","mehr_zur_auswahl":["einiges","vieles und","gär nix"]},{"meine_frage":"tom & jerry","ne_andere_frage":"mickey maus","was_willst_du":"oder","mehr_zur_auswahl":["manches","einiges","vieles und","gär nix"]},{"meine_frage":"dick und doof","ne_andere_frage":"minnie muas","was_willst_du":"nichts","mehr_zur_auswahl":["gär nix"]}]

const result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  return Object.keys(e).forEach(function(k) {
    if(!r[k]) r[k] = [].concat(e[k])
    else r[k] = r[k].concat(e[k])
  }), r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is good and quite close to being functional. With a few tweaks you could make it so: replace the if/else and assignments with a ternary return statement, and use that function in [array_map_associative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43004994/760706).

Answer (score 5):

You could use `reduce` method by passing a `callback` function as parameter.

The algorithm is follow: if final object already **contains** one key then you should initialize the key's value with an empty **array**. Otherwise, you should **append** to array value from all items from the array.

```js
let data = [{"meine_frage":"hier kommt die antwort","ne_andere_frage":"ne andere antwort","was_willst_du":"alles","mehr_zur_auswahl":["einiges","vieles und","gär nix"]},{"meine_frage":"tom & jerry","ne_andere_frage":"mickey maus","was_willst_du":"oder","mehr_zur_auswahl":["manches","einiges","vieles und","gär nix"]},{"meine_frage":"dick und doof","ne_andere_frage":"minnie muas","was_willst_du":"nichts","mehr_zur_auswahl":["gär nix"]}]

let result = data.reduce(function(obj, item){
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key){
    if(!obj[key]) obj[key] = [].concat(item[key])
    else {
       if(Array.isArray(item[key]))
         obj[key].push(...item[key])
       else
         obj[key].push(item[key]);
    }
  });
  return obj;
},{});
console.log([result]);
```

Answer (score 3):

This function will do the work:

```
const example = array => {
    let newObject = {}
    array.forEach((element) => {
        for(let key in element) {
            if(typeof element[key] === 'object') {
                element[key].forEach((el) => {
                    if(newObject[key] && newObject[key].length) {
                         newObject[key].push(el)
                    }
                    else {
                        newObject[key] = [el]
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                if(newObject[key] && newObject[key].length){
                    newObject[key].push(element[key])
                }
                else{
                    newObject[key] = [element[key]]
                }
            }
        }
    })
    return newObject
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` and check by `Array.isArray`, try below code

```js
var myArray = [{"meine_frage": "hier kommt die antwort","ne_andere_frage": "ne andere antwort","was_willst_du": "alles","mehr_zur_auswahl": ["einiges", "vieles und", "g\u00e4r nix"]}, {"meine_frage": "tom & jerry","ne_andere_frage": "mickey maus","was_willst_du": "oder","mehr_zur_auswahl": ["manches", "einiges", "vieles und", "g\u00e4r nix"]}, {"meine_frage": "dick und doof","ne_andere_frage": "minnie muas","was_willst_du": "nichts","mehr_zur_auswahl": ["g\u00e4r nix"]}];

var findKeyOf = function(key){ 
  var temp = myArray.map(function(e){
    return e[key]; 
  });
  var test = [];
  for(let i in temp){
    if(Array.isArray(temp[i]) ){
      test = test.concat(temp[i]);
    }else{
      test.push(temp[i])
    }
  }
  return test;
};

var newArr = [
    {meine_frage:findKeyOf('meine_frage')},
    {ne_andere_frage:findKeyOf('ne_andere_frage')},
    {was_willst_du:findKeyOf('was_willst_du')},
    {mehr_zur_auswahl:findKeyOf('mehr_zur_auswahl')},
]
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#reduce` as a accumulator and iterate through each key of object and `array#concat` the values.

```js
var data = [{ "meine_frage": "hier kommt die antwort", "ne_andere_frage": "ne andere antwort", "was_willst_du": "alles", "mehr_zur_auswahl": ["einiges", "vieles und", "g\u00e4r nix"] }, { "meine_frage": "tom & jerry", "ne_andere_frage": "mickey maus", "was_willst_du":"oder", "mehr_zur_auswahl": ["manches", "einiges", "vieles und", "g\u00e4r nix"] }, { "meine_frage": "dick und doof", "ne_andere_frage": "minnie muas", "was_willst_du": "nichts", "mehr_zur_auswahl": ["g\u00e4r nix"] }];

var merged = data.reduce((r,o) => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
    r[k] = (r[k] || []).concat(o[k]);
  })
  return r;
},{});

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
var data = [{
    "meine_frage": "hier kommt die antwort",
    "ne_andere_frage": "ne andere antwort",
    "was_willst_du": "alles",
    "mehr_zur_auswahl": ["einiges", "vieles und", "g\u00e4r nix"]

}, {
    "meine_frage": "tom & jerry",
    "ne_andere_frage": "mickey maus",
    "was_willst_du": "oder",
    "mehr_zur_auswahl": ["manches", "einiges", "vieles und", "g\u00e4r nix"]

}, {
    "meine_frage": "dick und doof",
    "ne_andere_frage": "minnie muas",
    "was_willst_du": "nichts",
    "mehr_zur_auswahl": ["g\u00e4r nix"]

}]

let myData = data.reduce((b , a)=> {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(key => {
        if (Object.keys(b).indexOf(key) > -1) {
            if (typeof a[key] === "object") {
                b[key] = [...b[key], ...a[key]]       
            } else {
                b[key].push(a[key])
            }
             
        } else {
            if (typeof a[key] === "object") {
                b[key] = [...a[key]]
            } else {
                b[key] = [a[key]]
            }                  
        }    
    })
    return b
}, {})

console.log(myData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Where did you used destructing assignment ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut, I updated my answer. It is the `spread operator`