# How to get a PHP function alike array_walk that will return an array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, closures, array-walk

Is there any built-in function existing in PHP alike `array_walk()` that will return an array instead of true or false?

For information, I am trying the following code but in the result of the code getting `OR` at the end of the string I need to remove this hence I need an alternative

```
$request_data = "Bablu"; //userdata 

$presentable_cols = array('id'=>'13141203051','name'=>'Bablu Ahmed','program'=>'B.Sc. in CSE', 'country'=>'Bangladesh');

function myfunction($value,$key,$request_data)
{
    echo " $key LIKE '% $request_data %' OR";
}
array_walk($presentable_cols,"myfunction", $request_data);
```

Result of the code:

```
id LIKE '% Bablu %' OR name LIKE '% Bablu %' OR program LIKE '% Bablu %' OR country LIKE '% Bablu %' OR
```

Comment: `array_map`. `array_walk` can modify array too. All functions are here - http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: But array_map can't take $userdata @u_mulder

Comment: What's $userdata!?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. What is `$userdata`? Instead of asking for a function that does __what__?, you should describe a real problem.

Comment: $userdata means parameter like array_walk(array,myfunction,parameter...) @Devon

Comment: @BabluAhmed you must give us more information. Please provide exemple code of $userdata and its context.

Comment: I have given more info @Rikard

Comment: @BabluAhmed Just see my answer.

Comment: @BabluAhmed Sorry not even that easy XD See my updated answer.

Comment: Your previous answer was more informative. How to return an array instead of true or false using array_map@Blackbam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The use keyword allows you to introduce local variables into the local
>   scope of an anonymous function. This is useful in the case where you
>   pass the anonymous function to some other function which you have no
>   control over.

Can not use array_map as this does not work with keys ([PHP's array_map including keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036160/phps-array-map-including-keys)). Here is a possible solution:

```
$request_data = "Bablu"; //userdata 

$presentable_cols = array('id'=>'13141203051','name'=>'Bablu Ahmed','program'=>'B.Sc. in CSE', 'country'=>'Bangladesh');

$my_arr = [];
$myfunction = function($value,$key) use ($request_data,&$my_arr)
{
    array_push($my_arr," $key LIKE '% $request_data %'");
};

array_walk($presentable_cols,$myfunction);

echo implode("OR",$my_arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't complicate things. Just use `foreach` to modify your array or to create a new one:

```
foreach ($presentable_cols as $key => $value) {
    $presentable_cols[$key] = "$key LIKE '% $request_data %'";
}
```

By the way, make sure to sanitize `$request_data`.