# Merge two associative arrays of associative arrays and preserve all keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, key

How to handle a key (`index`) of a parent array? I'm getting numeric keys, but I need an `index` as a key.
[Example.](https://3v4l.org/6SpI0)

Sample input:

```
$arrayFirst = [
  "index" => ['a' => '1'],
  ['a' => '2']
];

$arraySecond = [
  "index" => ['b' => '1'],
  ['b' => '2']
];
```

My code:

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function(...$items) {
            return array_merge(...$items);
        },
        $arrayFirst,
        $arraySecond
    )
);
```

Incorrect/Current output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'a' => '1',
    'b' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'a' => '2',
    'b' => '2',
  ),
)
```

Desired output:

```
array (
  'index' => 
  array (
    'a' => '1',
    'b' => '1',
  ),
  0 => 
  array (
    'a' => '2',
    'b' => '2',
  ),
)
```

Comment: ['array_map()` can't handle keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036160/phps-array-map-including-keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If keys of two arrays are complete the same, then you can try using func `array_combine()`:

```
var_dump(
    array_combine(
        array_keys($arrayFirst),
        array_map(
            function(...$items) {
                return array_merge(...$items);
            },
            $arrayFirst,
            $arraySecond
        )
    )
);
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55b90ba285ba36d0e9eab1c9ab2f46f800b615ab)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible workaround:

```
$arrayFirst = array("index" => array("keyFirst" => "valFirst"));
$arraySecond = array("index" => array("keySecond" => "valSecond"));
$result = ['index' => array_merge($arrayFirst['index'], $arraySecond['index'])];

var_dump($result);
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ba844bccd72dcc8fa26c1970243223daed48682)

Comment: This answer is not explained. This is not the asker's sample data. This snippet is not suitable as a technique to generate the asker's desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend only looping on the second array and directly modifying the first array.  Of course, if you don't want to modify the first array, you can make a copy of it and append the second array's data to that.

Anyhow, using a classic loop to synchronously merge the two arrays will be more performant, readable, and maintainable than a handful of native function calls.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hifIr))

```
foreach ($arrayFirst as $k => &$row) {
    $row = array_merge($row, $arraySecond[$k]);
}
var_export($arrayFirst);
```